# Orientation of SKNode in followPath Swift

Tags: ios, spritekit

I'm developing a game like price wheel where I need to touch the correct answer. For now I find replies where people says:

> Set yScale of SKNode to -1.

Or

> Set xScale of SKSpriteNode to xScale = xScale * -1.

I try but when the SKAction is executed, this take no effect. This is the code here I construct the SKNode and SKSpriteNodes:

```
func putNodesInScreen(){

    repeats++
    let wheel1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "find_roda_original.png")
    let wheel2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "find_roda_original.png")
    let plate = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "find_carro_lila.png")

    wheel1.position = CGPointMake(10, 10)
    wheel2.position = CGPointMake(300, 10)
    plate.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)

    nodes[repeats-1].addChild(wheel1)
    nodes[repeats-1].addChild(wheel2)
    nodes[repeats-1].addChild(plate)

    self.addChild(nodes[repeats-1])

    let angle : Float = -Float(M_PI)
    let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(angle), duration: 0.5)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate)
    wheel1.runAction(repeatAction, withKey: "rotate")
    wheel2.runAction(repeatAction, withKey: "rotate2")

    var sequence = SKAction.sequence([getArcPath(false), getArcPath(true)])

    nodes[repeats-1].runAction(sequence)


    }

    func getArcPath(second: Bool) -> SKAction{

        var radius: CGFloat = screenWidth*27/26 - (screenHeight/7/screenWidth/screenHeight)

        var centarArc = CGPointMake(screenWidth / 2, (((-radius) + screenHeight/2)*(1.01)))

        var end: CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI*(270-73+25)/180.0)

        var start: CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI*(270+73+25)/180.0)

        if(!second){
           start = start-((start-end)*(CGFloat(repeats)/13.0))
        }

         var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centarArc, radius: radius, startAngle: (start-3.1416), endAngle: end-3.1416, clockwise: false)

        return (second ? SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath,asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 250.0)) : SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 250.0))

    }
```

And this is the result:

[image]